# Finding out the destination YouTube URL when uploading videos to YouTube via youtube_it gem with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, youtube-api

I've gotten the 'youtube_it' working great in conjunction with Paperclip to handle video uploads through the browser using the following code:

videos_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @video = Video.new(params[:video])
    if @video.save
      uploader = YouTubeIt::Upload::VideoUpload.new( :username => AppConfig[:youtube_user], 
                                                     :password =>  AppConfig[:youtube_pass], 
                                                     :dev_key => AppConfig[:youtube_api_key])
      uploader.upload open( params[:video][:attachment] ), :title => @video.title,
                                                           :description => @video.description,
                                                           :category => 'some category',
                                                           :keywords => ['some keyword 1', "some keyword 2"]
      @video.deliver_video_notification
      flash[:notice] = 'Your video is under review for approval.<br/> Please check back in 48 hours.'
      redirect_to videos_url
    else
      @errors = @video.errors
      @current_video = params[:v].blank? ? Video.newest : Video.find(params[:v])
      render :action => :index
    end
  end
```

However once the video is uploaded, I have no idea what URL YouTube created for the video without manually logging into the YouTube channel and looking it up. I didn't see any callback in the logs or the response.body that revealed the destination. I'd like to programatically save the destination in some kind of after_save method. As it works right now, it is saving the video object, and after save it is uploading the video to youtube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `upload` method returns a `YouTubeIt::Model::Video`, which has a `player_url` attribute. So just catch the return value from the `upload` method, and call `player_url` on that, and voilà, you have the URL to the video. For a list of the other attributes that model has, check the [source code](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/blob/master/lib/youtube_it/model/video.rb).

Example:

```
def create
  @video = Video.new(params[:video])
  if @video.save
    uploader = YouTubeIt::Upload::VideoUpload.new( :username => AppConfig[:youtube_user], 
                                                   :password =>  AppConfig[:youtube_pass], 
                                                   :dev_key => AppConfig[:youtube_api_key])
    uploaded_video = uploader.upload open( params[:video][:attachment] ), :title => @video.title,
                                                         :description => @video.description,
                                                         :category => 'some category',
                                                         :keywords => ['some keyword 1', "some keyword 2"]

    puts uploaded_video.player_url # This will print the URL to the log

    @video.deliver_video_notification
    flash[:notice] = 'Your video is under review for approval.<br/> Please check back in 48 hours.'
    redirect_to videos_url
  else
    @errors = @video.errors
    @current_video = params[:v].blank? ? Video.newest : Video.find(params[:v])
    render :action => :index
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the list of videos uploaded by the user and choosing the latest one?

`$ client.my_videos`

https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it

Comment: Not a bad idea. Problem is that this is using the developer's key so all the videos are being uploaded to a single channel, not the individual user's channel. If we use that same technique with our single channel, we cannot account for video processing time or length of video to make the assumption that the latest video uploaded belongs to Video.last. Thanks for the brainstorm

Comment: 1. Doesn't "client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:username => "youtube_username", :password =>  "youtube_passwd", :dev_key => "developer_key")" let you upload videos into the user's channel?
2. Have you tried using OAuth (it says youtube_it supports it).

I wish I could verify these myself but I am not in a position to do so right now!

Comment: 1. It does let you, but the desired behavior is that all the video gets uploaded to a designated client channel.

Comment: Plus I've seen the oath way, but I think only works in a 2 part form, and I want to do it all at once with the create of the Video object.